# Extend the Visual Studio C++ Build Process

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, build, project, target

A found an article ([Extend the Visual Studio Build Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724(VS.80).aspx)) that explained how to override build targets in a C# project file.  I tested this, and it seems to work well.  However, what I really want to do is override a build target in a C++ project (with Visual Studio 2005).  The problem is that C++ projects use different XML.  Instead of having `<project>` as the root, C++ projects have `<VisualStudioProject>` as the root.  When I add the `<target>` tag to a C++ project file and try to open the project in Visual Studio, I get this error:

> The following error has occurred during XML parsing:
>
> File:
>   [*Path to Project File*].vcproj
>   Line: 304 Column: 30 Error Message:
>   Element 'Target' is unexpected
>   according to content model of parent
>   element 'VisualStudioProject'.
>
> The file
>   '[*Path to Project File*].vcproj'
>   has failed to load.

How can I override a Visual Studio build target for a C++ project?  Or is there a better way to customize what happens during a C++ build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2005 there are no build "targets" for C++ builds as the C++ build system does not use MSBuild.

However, VC++2005 defines the *Pre-Build*, *Pre-Link*, *Post-Build* Events as well as the ability to add a *Custom Build Step* for non-standard files.

You may be able to achieve what you want using these settings.

Note:

- VC++2005 projects can be built using MSBuild, it's just not what Visual Studio does out of the box.
- Visual Studio 2010 uses MSBuild for all project types.

Comment: Unfortunately, I want to modify the "Clean" build.  I don't think I can achieve what I want to do with Pre-Build, Pre-Link, and Post-Build because those run all the time for all builds.  Unless there is a way to set up conditional build steps based on the type of build, it looks like I might be stuck.